# If $R_1$ and $R_2$ have the same cardinality, then $R_1 = R_2$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory

In proving one direction (the part **at most**) of this statement from [Wikipedia](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Subgroups_of_cyclic_groups#/Finite_cyclic_groups)

> [image]

I re-phrase it as below theorem. Could you please leave me some **hints** (not involved modular arithmetic) to prove it.

---

Let

- $0<p<q < N$ be natural numbers.
- $R_1$ be the set of remainders when all multiples of $p$ is divided by $N$.
- $R_2$ be the set of remainders when all multiples of $q$ is divided by $N$.

> If $R_1$ and $R_2$ have the same cardinality, then $R_1 = R_2$.

Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: To be clear... are you really intending a $1$ and $2$ there rather than a $p$ and $q$?  It should be obvious what $R_1$ is equal to and there are only two possibilities for what $R_2$ is equal to.

Comment: @JMoravitz I'm sorry for typos ans not clear statements. Please see my edit!

Comment: If $p=7,\,q=11,\,N=13$ then $R_1=\{6,13\}$ and $R_2=\{2,13\}$ and $|R_1|=|R_2|=2.$

Comment: Hi @DanielWainfleet $R_1 = R_2 = \{0,1,\ldots, 12\}$.

Comment: Hi @DanielWainfleet, I'm sorry for my incorrect statement. I should have written "$R_1$ be the set of remainders when all multiples of $p$ is divided by $N$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT.

Let $a=\gcd (p,N).$ Let $p=p'a$ and $N=N'a.$ Then $\gcd(p',N')=1.$

Now $p'ax=px=Ny+r=N'ay+r$ with $r\in R_1$ iff $r=r'a$ for some  $ r'\in R'_1$, where $R'_1$ is the set of remainders when multiples of $p'$ are divided by $N'.$

So $R_1=\{ar': r'\in R'_1\}.$

Use $\gcd(p',N')=1$ to obtain $R'_1=\{0,..., N'-1\},$ which has $N'=N/a=N/\gcd(p,N)$ members.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose m,n  are the largest integers such that $N=mp+r=nq+r'$ for some $0\le r\lt p,0\le r'\lt q$. Then $p, 2p,... ,(m-1)p$ divided by $N$ have remainders equal to themselves. Similarly, the remainders of $q,...,(n-1)q$ divided by $N$ are themselves.

If $r=0, mp$ divided by $N$  have remainder $0$, otherwise it has remainder $mp$, and similarly for $r'$.

Now, for any $k\in \Bbb N, (m+k)p\equiv kp-r (\mod N)$. If $kp-r\gt N$, we can find some $k'$ such that $kp-r\equiv k'p-ur(\mod N)$ and $k'p-ur\le N$ for some $u\in \Bbb N$.  When $kp-r\le N=mp+r\implies (k-m)p\le 2r\lt 2p\implies k\lt m+2\implies k\le m+1$. When $kp-r\gt N,$ we may just consider $k'p-ur\le N=mp+r\implies (k'-m)p\le (u+1)r\lt (u+1)p\implies k'\le m+u$

Notice that for any $k'$ and $u$ we have $(k'-1)p-(u-1)r\lt k'p-ur\lt k'p-(u-1)r$. Hence $$R_1=\{p,...,(m-1)p,mp\;\text{or} \;0,p-r,...,mp-r,(m+1)p-r,p-2r,...,(m+2)p-2r,...\}$$ Similarly, $$R_2=\{q,...,(n-1)q,nq\;\text{or} \;0,q-r',...,nq-r',(n+1)q-r',q-2r',...,(n+2)q-2r',...\}$$
Then our desired result is clear.

(This is due to FormulaWriter: Notice that $|R_1|=N$ regardless of $m$ if and only if $N, p$ are coprime.)

Comment: How can you conclude that $R_1=\{0,1,...,p-1,p,...,mp-1\}, R_2=\{0,1,...,q-1,q,...,nq-1\}$?

Comment: @LAD That's why I said I may have interpreted the question wrong. I think you meant $R_1$ is the set of all possible remainders when N is divided by p, 2p, 3p, ... up to largest possible multiple of p right?

Comment: I mean $R_1$ is the set of all possible remainders when $N$ is divided by $\{np \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$.

Comment: When N is divided by any element of the set?

Comment: Yeap, that's what I meant.

Comment: Seeing the discussion under the question, I think you meant to have N or p, q vary right? Cause if not then Daniel would actually be right, and your proposition (and thus this answer) would be wrong

Comment: I fix $(N,p,q)$. Let me take an example. Let $(p,q,N) = (2,4,6)$. Then the set of all multiples of $2$ is $\{0,2,4,6,8,...\}$, while that of $4$ is $\{0,4,8,12,16,...\}$. Then $R_1= R_2 = \{0,2,4\}$.

Comment: @LAD $R_1=\{0,2,6\}$ from $6\div 2,6\div 4, 6\div 8$

Comment: Also this seems inconsistent with what you wrote when replying to Daniel in the comments of your question

Comment: For $R_1$, I meant $0 = 0 \mod 6$, $4 = 4 \mod 6$, $2 = 8 \mod 6$, ...

Comment: OMG, my bad english. I should have written "...when all multiples of $p$ is divided by $N$"

Comment: Please see my edit!

Comment: Take $p=10$,$N=11$. Your current statement says $R_1=\{0\} \cup \{0,10\}$ instead of $R_1=\{0,1,2,\dots,10\}$. Try again! :-)

Comment: @FormulaWriter Do you think it would work as intended if OP phrases it as  "all possible remainders of any multiple of p divided by N"?

Comment: @Divide1918 I suspect there is an issue whan you claim the existence of $k'$, which leads to the following consequence: $R_1$ contains at most $2m+2$ elements.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Do you mean that $R_1$ actually may contain 2m+2 elements?

Comment: @Divide1918 I mean $R_1$ actually can contain far more than $2m+2$ elements, as in the case $p=10, N=11$.

Comment: @FormulaWriter Seems like it may contain up to 3m+3 elements

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109921/discussion-between-formulawriter-and-divide1918).